# selector is in different size than a "normal" image

Tags: android, image, selector, drawable

I have a weird problem. When I am doing this:

```
btnSleeping.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.selector_sleeping_on));
```

the image is smaller than when I am doing this: `btnSleeping.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.sleeping_on));`

sleeping_on is an image and selector_sleeping_on is a selector.
this is my selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sleeping_on" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sleeping" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- default -->
```

I have the sleeping_on and sleeping_off images only in "drawable-xhdpi".
Why is it that the selector is not appearing the same size as a normal imageViewand how can I make them the same size?

Comment: Do btn_sleeping_on and btn_sleeping have the same size?

Comment: Probably you can try my answer and have a look.

Comment: you are right!!  I am an idiot :) they are not the same size. sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Thing can be the image it self are of different size in this case which you are talking about,

And one more thing you can do is you can **fix** the size of the selector too.

Following is snippet to fix the size.

**Note** : Width and Height values you can change as you want.

```
<item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <size android:width="30" android:height="40"/>
  <solid android:color="#000000" />
 </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: yea!  you are right.  A very poor mistake by my side. the images are not the same size...